# Change progress bar color in Primeng

Tags: css, angular, primeng

How could we change the progress bar colour in Primeng. In the progress bar documentation it lists down

```
ui-progressbar-value
```

as the Element whose width changes according to value.

But when in the CSS when I set

```
.ui-progressbar-value {
  background-color: #ef5439;
}
```

It does not change anything. Infact I don't see any color.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about adding `!important` like `background-color: #ef5439 !important;`?

Comment: I tried this still no change.

Comment: If you are using it with angular then you have to use `::ng-deep`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add your own unique class in your progress bar like below 
**class="customProgress"** and then try to override it in your scss or css file. 
Hope it will work

```
<p-progressBar class="customProgress" [value]="value"></p-progressBar>



.customProgress .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-label {
    color: yellow;
}

.customProgress .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: @codestruggle just updated my answer...and it is working perfectly in my app. Earlier solution was also working except value color was not getting changed.

Comment: Hi @AlokVishwakarma thanks for your valuable answer,i have been searching for this from last 2 hours.Yes it is working!.Please attach the plnkr for this.So others should not struggle ;)

Comment: Thanks Alok, and thanks Rajesh for confirming it works, I did not get time to run my project again.

Comment: @Rajesh Choudhary here you go with plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/nPQqOqA6VIlcMh5mOByL?p=preview 
There are some changes in given answer it is in scss format and  in plunk i have written in CSS and also use encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None to make it work.

Comment: @AlokVishwakarma could you change your answer a bit, because the CSS in the answer does not seem to work but only CSS in your plunker works!!!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @codestruggle ...updated the answer...earlier format works in .scss now updated in plain CSS format

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the result with the following configuration:

**HTML**

```
<p-progressBar [value]="progressValue"
               [ngClass]="'customProgress'">
</p-progressBar>
```

In the **CSS** file, this is what you have to add:

```
::ng-deep .customProgress .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
    background: #ef5439;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions did not work for with primeng 11. I achieved the result in this way

```
 `<p-progressBar [value]="progressValue" class="customProgress"></p-progressBar> `
```

and with theming property CSS

```
::ng-deep .customProgress .p-progressbar-label {
  background: #ef5439;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular prime ng components use below method of style to change progress bar color

```html
<p-progressBar [style]="{'background':'red'}"></p-progressBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

And for have a green progressBar at 100%:

```
<p-progressBar [value]="rate" 
class="customProgress" 
[ngClass]="{'customProgressGreen': rate == 100}"
></p-progressBar>
```

With CSS code :

```
.customProgressGreen .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
    background: green;
}
```